# I am trying to use VBA code to save inkpicture contents, can only use vb.net or C#

Tags: vba

I found this code that is missing the function call in the last line, any ideas on what the save to file command would be?, I'll just kludge it in.

```
'CODE to SAVE InkPicture to FILE
Dim objInk As MSINKAUTLib.InkPicture
Dim bytArr() As Byte
Dim File1 As String
File1 = "C:\" & TrainerSig & ".gif"
Set objInk = Me.InkPicture2.Object
If objInk.Ink.Strokes.Count > 0 Then
    bytArr = objInk.Ink.Save(2)
    fSaveFile bytArr, File1
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a kludgy version of saving `.InkPicture` with VBA code in Access 2007 to a `.isf` file.

```
Private Sub Command283_Click()
    'CODE to SAVE InkPicture to FILE
    Dim objInk As MSINKAUTLib.InkPicture
    Dim bytArr() As Byte
    Dim File1 As String

    File1 = "C:\test.isf"

    Set objInk = Me.InkPicture2.Object

    If objInk.Ink.Strokes.Count > 0 Then
        bytArr = objInk.Ink.Save(2)
        Open File1 For Binary As #1
        Put #1, , bytArr
        Close #1
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You answered your own question?

Comment: It's a dirty job, but someone has to do it, I would like additional solutions as well.  Now trying to merge ink with background pic

Answer (score 0):

I tried zaphod23's solution and it did not work for me. I also thought it quite strange that the solution would save in a .isf format, normally people want to save inkPicture contents to an image file (jpg, gif, etc.). It took me a while to hunt down the pieces of this code and put it together, so I'll post it here for others who might find it useful.

This takes an inkPicture object used for a signature panel in a Microsoft Access form, saves the contents as a gif image, then puts the image in an image object on the form (which is useful because the inkPicture contents will not show up when you go to print the form).

```
On Error Resume Next
Dim imgBytes() As Byte
Dim sFilePathAndName As String

imgBytes = Me.signaturePanel.Ink.Save(IPF_GIF)

If (UBound(imgBytes) = 0) Then
    MsgBox ("Please enter your signature")
Else
    sFilePathAndName = (Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\images\system\signatures\" & "signature")
    Open sFilePathAndName For Binary Access Write As #1
    Put #1, 1, imgBytes
    Close #1
    Me.imgSignature.Picture = sFilePathAndName
End If
```